# Clean GeForce GT 220 still overheating with 3D acceleration

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, overheating

Everytime I push my GeForce GT 220 even a little bit it gets very hot. It seems to only be when 3D is used.

```
GPU    : GeForce GT 220 [PCI Express x16 Gen1 / 1024 MB] 
Screen : GNR TB2200W
OS     : Ubuntu [NVidia Driver Version 304.116]
```

I have had the PC apart a few times thinking it must be dirty but and it is now shiny clean and running with fan switched to 100% and if I run anything even remotely GPU intensive (games using 3D acceleration) the GPU gets so hot (90°C in no time) that I must quit or face a heat based auto power off.

Is this a thing with the GT 220 or the result of poor driver?

Is there anything that I can do to cool this thing down so I can enjoy it's graphical power?

I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you get a picture of your case open ? Perhaps the arrangement of fans isn't optimal ?

Comment: The GT 220 is a pretty slow GPU especially by today's standards. There's no reason for it to overheat unless there's a hardware defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fans aren't pulling enough hot air out of the case, then you could always get one of [these fans](http://dx.com/p/evercool-sb-f1-pci-slot-system-bearing-blower-fan-black-red-silver-dc-12v-228580#.Ux0ThYW5JcY) and mount it under the graphics card.

Comment: I've wondered about that. There is space to add and other airflow fan feeding on to the GPU but I need to know if it is the GPU needing air or the GPU being abused by a bad driver. I'm going to order some more case fans if I can afford it (money is silly tight at the moment which is why I want to do anything I can to avoid spending first).

Comment: If you have an old/dead PSU, they're a good source for fans.

Comment: I've ordered a £3 fan while completing an ebuyer order for a family member. We will see if this helps in a few days when it arrives. I will let you know if this does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your airflow, is it potentially drawing in hot air?
Maybe you need to adjust your case fans to ensure it is getting enough cool air.

Other than that and maybe trying to update drivers I don't have much to add.